# Fixed menu doesn't hold position when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fixed, parallax

I'm using this code for my fixed menu:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function my_function() {
        var scroll_value = document.body.scrollTop;
        if (scroll_value > 0) {
            $("#my_div").fadeOut(500);
        }
        else {
            $("#my_div").fadeIn(500);
        }
        if (scroll_value >= 650) {
            $('#sl_userNav').show('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 750);
        }
        else {
            $('#sl_userNav').hide('slide', { direction: 'up' }, 750);
        }
        document.getElementById("sl_userNav").style.marginTop = scroll_value.toString() + "px";
    }
    setInterval(my_function, 5);
    my_function();
});
```

jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.2 has been included.

I have 2 problems with that code:

- the first one - "#my_div" disappear but not in a smooth way (fadeIn/fadeOut doesn't work)
- the second - my fixed menu jump up and down on fast scrolling

I  can't use just a 'fixed' in CSS because due to my parallax effect it is scroll like the rest of the page.

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle? to improve the question.

Comment: Could you add a [Stack snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the "Code snippet" button?

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, have you considered using [.scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) instead of calling a function every 5 milliseconds?